# php code for connecct with android

Tags: php, android

I try to connect android with database and display all data but my data does not appear what the wrong? Is there something wrong in my php code?

The result was empty page, I try more than way and all of it give same result.

```
<?php

$response = array();

require "conn.php";

$n ="SELECT * FROM information";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$n);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product = array();
        $product ["parcode"]=$row["id"];
        $product ["scientific_name"]=$row["scientific_name"];
        $product ["trade_name"]=$row["trade_name"];
        $product ["side_effect"]=$row["side_effect"];
        $product ["indication"]=$row["indication"];
        $product ["conduction"]=$row["conduction"];
        $product ["no.of_take_drud"]=$row["no.of_take_drud"];

        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";
}

echo json_encode($response);
die();

?>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting and see if there is any error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).